# How can I apply a function referencing a specific column and leading values based on a conditional statement applied to a different column

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains datetimes, turbidity values, and sampling method codes. I want to select any rows that use the sampling method code 10 or 40 and then calculate a new turbidity value for those rows. The new turbidity value will need to be time weighted so I need to reference the two turbidity values that follow the one I am recalculating. I am new to R programming so I am struggling a bit with this one.

Example data:

| datetime | TURB | sample_meth | twm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2018 12:15 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 12:30 | 1.6 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 12:45 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 13:00 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 14:15 | 1.3 | 10 |  |
| 5/1/2018 14:30 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 14:45 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 15:00 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 15:15 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 15:30 | 1.3 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 15:45 | 1.3 | 40 |  |
| 5/1/2018 16:00 | 1.3 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 16:15 | 1.4 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 16:30 | 1.3 | NA |  |
| 5/1/2018 16:45 | 1.3 | 4033 |  |
| 5/1/2018 17:00 | 1.3 | NA |  |

I first attempted an ifelse function:

```
twtbl$twm<-ifelse(twtbl$sample_meth==10|40,(((twtbl$TURB[i]+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1)/2)*15)+((lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1)+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],2)/2)*15))/30)
```

I have tried defining a function and using that in a for loop (I don't think I am doing it correctly), and I also attempted just putting the calculation in a for loop for the time weighted means of all values, expecting to then clean them up.

```
  for(i in twtbl$TURB){
  twtbl$twm<-(((((twtbl$TURB[i]+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1))/2)*15)+(((lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1)+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],2))/2)*15))/30)
}
```

the syntax of the time weighted calculation I tried was based on information I found regarding lag and lead values:

```
(((((twtbl$TURB[i]+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1))/2)*15)+(((lead(twtbl$TURB[i],1)+lead(twtbl$TURB[i],2))/2)*15))/30)
```

In an Excel sheet this calculation would be something like:

=((((B$1+B$2)/2)*15)+(((B$2+B$3)/2)*15))/30

Comment: There are only 2 rows with `sample_meth` equal to 10 o 40 and you have 3 values in your formula. With the posted data the formula cannot be computed.

Comment: I need to calculate values in the turbidity column. I would like to identify which ones to calculate based on if the sample_meth meets the criteria of == 10|40

Comment: For example: The calculated twm for the row with sample_meth == 10 would be...  ((((1.3+1.4)/2)*15)+(((1.4+1.4)/2)*15))/30 = 1.375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also do it in base R, let's develop the code in order. (This won't be the most efficient or shortest, but I'll prioritize clarity.)

First, make up some data. (The following elides the cases where a 10 or a 40 are close to each other, or near the end of the data. You'll need to decide what to do in those cases.)

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 10
twtbl <- data.frame(
  date.time=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), by=123, length.out=n), 
  turb=sample.int(n=5, size=n, replace=TRUE), 
  sample_meth=c(10, 999, 999, 40, 999, 999, 999, 10, 999, 999)
)
```

```
> twtbl
    date.time turb sample_meth
1  2010-01-01    1          10
2  2010-05-04    4         999
3  2010-09-04    1         999
4  2011-01-05    2          40
5  2011-05-08    5         999
6  2011-09-08    3         999
7  2012-01-09    2         999
8  2012-05-11    3          10
9  2012-09-11    3         999
10 2013-01-12    1         999
```

This is R we don't need a loop :-) . We can get the row numbers of which turbidities need to be fixed:

```
rowsToFix <- which(twtbl$sample_meth %in% c(10, 40))
```

Next, a function to fix them. Given a row number and a dataframe (in this case `twtbl`), it returns a new turbidity value. (Note that this version assumes the rows are sorted by date. If not, and it's impractical to sort the dataframe first, you can write a version using `lead()` although I'm not certain the syntax you used above is correct. Also, I hope this gets the calculations right, I may have misunderstood?)

```
recalculate <- function(i, df) {
  newValue <- (df$turb[i] + df$turb[i+1] * 15/2 + 
    (df$turb[i+1] + df$turb[i+2] * 15/2)) / 30
  return(newValue)
}
```

Finally, we can apply this to the dataframe. We'll make a copy of `twtb1` and modify that, so we can compare:

```
fixedTwtbl <- twtbl
fixedTwtbl[rowsToFix, "turb"] <- 
  sapply(X=rowsToFix, FUN=function(u) recalculate(i=u, df=twtbl))
```

```
> twtbl
    date.time turb sample_meth
1  2010-01-01    1          10
2  2010-05-04    4         999
3  2010-09-04    1         999
4  2011-01-05    2          40
5  2011-05-08    5         999
6  2011-09-08    3         999
7  2012-01-09    2         999
8  2012-05-11    3          10
9  2012-09-11    3         999
10 2013-01-12    1         999
> fixedTwtbl
    date.time   turb sample_meth
1  2010-01-01 1.4167          10
2  2010-05-04 4.0000         999
3  2010-09-04 1.0000         999
4  2011-01-05 2.2333          40
5  2011-05-08 5.0000         999
6  2011-09-08 3.0000         999
7  2012-01-09 2.0000         999
8  2012-05-11 1.2000          10
9  2012-09-11 3.0000         999
10 2013-01-12 1.0000         999
```

Comment: That took care of it, I did need to change the calculation a bit but otherwise it worked just as needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following is untested, since the data doesn't meet the question's criteria. It uses package `zoo`, function `rollapplyr` to compute the formula. I have simplified the formula but the original, coded in R, is still in the function body.

```
f_aux <- function(x){
  #(15*(x[1] + x[2])/2 + 15*(x[2] + x[3])/2)/30
  (x[1] + 2*x[2] + x[3])/4
}

i <- with(twtbl, sample_meth %in% c(10, 40))
twtbl$twm <- NA_real_
twtbl$twm[i] <- zoo::rollapplyr(twtbl$TURB[i], width = 3, FUN = f_aux)
```

Comment: When I run this code I receive a warning message:   In twtbl$twm[i] <- zoo::rollapplyr(twtbl$TURB[i], width = 3, FUN = f_aux) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length